# .NET Core - FluentValidation - cross field validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I try to cross validate 2 fields.

At least one must be provided by the html form.

```
RuleFor(x => x.Email).Matches(Tools.EmailValidator).Length(5, 100).When(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Login));
RuleFor(x => x.Login).Matches(Tools.FreeTextValidator).Length(8, 100).When(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email));
```

- is `When()` the function to use? Or should I use `Unless()`?
- are rules going to be applied even if both fields are not empty?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your rules like this to be more readable:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Email)
.NotNull().NotEmpty()
.WithMessage("Some Message")
.Length(5, 100)
.WithMessage("Some Message") 
.Matches(Tools.EmailValidator)
.WithMessage("Some Message")
```

This order works better.or If you want to use when , you can follow the below:

```
When(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email), () => {
  RuleFor(x => x.Email).Matches(Tools.EmailValidator);
  RuleFor(x => x.Email).Length(5, 100);
}).Otherwise(() => {
 RuleFor("some other rules here").Matches("SomeValidator");
});
```

or if you want to stop on first failure:

```
this.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;

When(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Login), () => {
     RuleFor(x => x.Email)
    .Matches(Tools.EmailValidator)
    .Length(5, 100));

When(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email), () => {
     RuleFor(x => x.Login)
    .Matches(Tools.FreeTextValidator)
    .Length(8, 100));
```

Comment: yet it does not answer the question

Comment: so, You mean, if the value of the input is empty or null, we shouldn't validate the input? right?

Comment: (I removed the ! ) seems more logical, but I meant that if both values are provided, then non validations are done...since validations are only done if the other field is null

Comment: I need to validate at least one field